# How to find column value based on row and row data in Excel

Tags: excel, formulas

I'm hoping this is pretty straight forward but I'm having a heck of a time figuring this out.  So, hopefully you can help!

Here's the situation: I have an Excel sheet that allows users to choose a value from a drop-down list that is supplied by a range on another sheet.  The values in the drop-down are "Row Headers" (if that makes sense) from a larger table.  The table has many columns.  The values within the table are either "on" of "off" (binary).

I want to create a new table that correlates the "Row Headers" with the Column Headers only where the intersecting value is "on".  The graphic depicts the desired result.  Any help is much appreciated!

[image: Desired Result]

Comment: Getting several results for the same condition is tricky. Check this document: https://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/use-index-lookup-multiple-values-list. I can't elaborate a solution right now.

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved with the process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20543651/1505120) and then filtering the resulting table to delete rows showing `0` and then their entire column.